# Opened raid1 in raid0, what now?

Tags: linux, software-raid, raid1, raid0

I accidentally opened my 1 disk raid1 as raid0 with mdadm --create, and this looks like it overwrote the default raid meta info, and makes my device detected as raid0 with mdadm --assemble --scan.
For obvious reasons I can't see my partition currently, so I'm sure I didn't write anything to the partition.

Is there a safe way to get that 1 disk raid1 back without losing data on my disk?

Many thanks,
Clooney

Update:

Thanks for the quick replies. I may have not been specific enough, let me fix that.

Scenario: - I have a raid1 where sda1 and sdb1 are in /dev/md0, operating fine. - My sdb starts failing, so I remove sdb and take it back to get my warranty in place. - I boot from my rescure CD which confuses my drives order: I have 2 sata ports on my mb and 4 other sata ports on a Sil SATA card, i.e. the difference when loaded as a kernel module vs compiled into the kernel can cause such things - so after all i make the mistake to say mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=0 --raid-devices=1 /dev/sda1 -f and have my md1 created I figure the mixup.

I did not wipe the partition containing my raid1 data. I did not create a new filesystem (as I realized hopefully on time).

However I noticed that mdadm metadata may have been changed to v1.2 - which I believe means nothing else but it's kept elsewhere - making me also think that the previous raid meta info should be still available.

So the real questions behind this are: What does mdadm --create do exactly? Would mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=0 on the same partition solve this or would it result in an even bigger trouble? Can I, and if so how, find the previous meta data (which I didn't see any indication of getting deleted/wiped/etc) and use it to reconstruct my faulty /dev/md0?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I recommend that you create another copy of your HD drives. This is necessary to avoid data loss in case you made a mistake while trying to fix your raid.

You can use the following command to create the raid1 array:

```
$ sudo mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
```

Of course, you can customize the above command according to your needs.

You can check the raid status using: `cat /proc/mdstat`.

You can also check the `man mdadm` for more help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have a method of backing up the system if you plan to use RAID1, to I won't go into that.

You can't simply change from RAID0 to 1. You would have to create a new array, which would wipe out all data on the drives. You could make a backup, create a RAID1 array, then restore your backup onto the new array.